# Case sensitive searching in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a query which searches rows in a database for matching strings. An example row may be:

```
This is a row which contains a String
```

The query that I am currently running is syntactically identical to

```
SELECT table.column FROM table WHERE table.column LIKE "*String*"
```

although it returns every row where the text "string" is found, regardless of case.

Does MS Access 2010 have any sort of case sensitive string comparator that I should be using instead of this?

Comment: The old trick WHERE lower(table.column) LIKE lower("*String*") may work.

Comment: The query needs to match the case word I am searching for, e.g. if I search for "Total", rows containing "total" should not be returned

Comment: Sometimes I tend to read and comment too fast, while doing other stuff at the same time... Sorry.

Comment: That's fine, I must admit that I am guilty of doing this as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to resort to VBA methods, I'm afraid. Fortunately, VBA methods can be used in JET SQLs (although performance might not be the best). The VBA `Instr` method allows you to specify the comparison mode (0 = binary = case-sensitive):

```
SELECT table.column FROM table WHERE INSTR(table.column, "String", 0) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `LIKE '*String*'` **not** `LIKE "*String*"`

See more [LIKE condition in MS Access](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like2007.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Instr](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/instr.php):

```
SELECT t.FieldName
FROM Table t
WHERE ((InStr(1,[FieldName],"aB",0)>"0"));
```