# Syntax error when attempting case sensitive SELECT in Access

Tags: sql, select, case-sensitive, ms-access-2016

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831105/how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search-in-where-clause-im-using-sql-server), I've tried to perform a case-sensitive `SELECT` query on a column in my table, but it's returning a Syntax Error. The query is:

```
SELECT [EntityValueID] 
FROM [EntityValue] 
WHERE [EntityCode] = "&oK;" COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

I'm not sure what I've missed here - is there something I need to download to get collation working? Or is it something apparently obvious? It highlights the `COLLATE` keyword when I attempt to run the query, so I guess the error is here, but it seems just like the answer I referenced.

Comment: I don't think MS Access supports `COLLATE`.

Comment: Ah ... then I guess my question is, how can I perform a case-sensitive SELECT in Access.

Comment: @Andre Yes it does, thank you. I just found that solution too.

Comment: or an alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277646/case-sensitive-searching-in-ms-access